# React Router Load Any of One Component in else

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I have created a react app with protected route. Now App is on stage where I can not any strong change in it . The Thing is In my `App.js` component i have a condition

```
<div className="App">
      {
        (props.auth) ? <MainView /> : <Signin /> 
      }
</div>
```

`MainView` component has all the routes written in it. And `props.auth` is redux state. This is working fine without any challenge. But now I want to use `SignUp` component which renders when or if user want to create-account.
But I mentioned My route is written in `MainView` component. So if I fill singup route I only see `<SignIn>` component because of the else condition in `app.js`. How can i Call `<SignUp>` component without changing more structure or in easier way.

To be more specific

```
<div className="App">
    {
      (props.auth) ? <MainView /> : <Signin /> || <SignUp /> //I want to render both of them if user not logged in. And they both are seperate component.
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the two components in a `div` or use a React Fragment.

```
<div className="App">
    {
      (props.auth) ? <MainView /> : <> <Signin /> <SignUp /> </> // Using a React fragment
    }
</div>
```

```
<div className="App">
    {
      (props.auth) ? <MainView /> : <div> <Signin /> <SignUp /> </div> // Using a div
    }
</div>
```

Update:

```
<div className="App">
    {
      (props.auth) ? <MainView /> : <>
          flag ? <Signin /> : <SignUp />
      </> // The flag must change values depending on what the user chooses to see; Its default value may be for SignIn
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Ok..Thank you for your time. But By doing this I see both component on same page. While loading the signIn I condition render in signIn component. `i.e` if state is true -. load dashboard or else show sign-in. How can i write code so that both sign-in and sign-up are available.

Comment: @RitikSingh I understand. If you want the simplest solution, maintain a hook/state variable to decide whether to show the SignIn component or the SignUp component. Later, add buttons in both the SignIn and SignUp to modify the variable, and then use a condition to display the two components.
I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can either extract those to components into a new component like Login page and render this in the else.

Or wrap the compoennts into a fragment:

```
<div className="App">
    {
      (props.auth) ? <MainView /> : 
<>
<Signin />
<SignUp />
</>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Ok..Thank you for your time. But By doing this I see both component on same page. While loading the signIn I condition render in signIn component. i.e if state is true -. load dashboard or else show sign-in. How can i write code so that both sign-in and sign-up are available. –

Answer (score 1):

Wrap then in a react fragment or div.

```
<div className="App">
{
  (props.auth) ? <MainView /> : <> <Signin /> <SignUp /> </> 
}
```